# Using object promise inside embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

As the title says, I would like to use the data of an async function inside an embed.

This is my embed code:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content
        .slice(prefix.length)
        .trim()
        .split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'cd') {
    const  cdEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    
      .setColor('#0099ff')
      .setTitle('test')
      .setDescription('test embed')
      /*.setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/lrb3uWm.png')*/
      .addFields(
            { name:  count(client), value: 0 , inline: true, },
        )
      .setTimestamp();
    message.channel.send(cdEmbed);
    }
});
```

The function created inside a new `count.js` file:

```js
const fetchData = async () => {
  if (startingHour <= 0 && startingMin <= 0) {
    importantData = 'Expired'
  } else {
    importantData = `${startingHour} hours and ${startingMin} minutes`
  }
}
const getText = () => {
  return `${importantData}`
}
// ...
```

I tried to use `count(client)` in the embed field but it's not working as expected, it's returning `[object Promise]` and not the value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the return value of the promise and once you have that, set the `name` in `addField()`.

You can either use the `.then()` method of `count()`:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'cd') {
    count(client)
      .then((name) => {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setColor('#0099ff')
          .setTitle('test')
          .setDescription('test embed')
          /*.setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/lrb3uWm.png')*/
          .addFields({ name, value: 0, inline: true })
          .setTimestamp();
        message.channel.send(embed);
      })
      .catch(console.log);
  }
});
```

Or use async/await:

```js
client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'cd') {
    try {
      const name = await count(client);
      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setTitle('test')
        .setDescription('test embed')
        /*.setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/lrb3uWm.png')*/
        .addFields({ name, value: 0, inline: true })
        .setTimestamp();
      message.channel.send(embed);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Both are working, TY!
I have one more question. For some reason i am now getting 'undefined' im my `.addFields({ name, value: 0, inline: true })` and the data appears in top of embed instead. Is it possible to return only the constructor string to fix that or is there any other way?